# Define Next Start Point When Number of Items Unknown

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-4.0, parallel-processing

I have a web service I need to query and it takes a value that supports pagination for its data. Due to the amount of data I need to fetch and how that service is implemented I intended to do a series of concurrent http web requests to accumulate this data.

Say I have number of threads and page size how could I assign each thread to pick its starting point that doesn't overlap with the other thread? Its been a long time since I took parallel programming and I'm floundering a bit. I know I could find my start point with something like `start = N/numThreads * threadNum` however I don't know N. Right now I just spin up X threads and each loop until they get no more data. Problem is they tend to overlap and I end up with duplicate data. I need unique data and not to waste requests.

Right now I have code that looks something like this. This is one of many attempts and I see why this is wrong but its better to show something. The goal is to in parallel collect pages of data from a webservice:

```
       int limit = pageSize;

        data = new List<RequestStuff>();
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

        for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
        {
            tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        List<RequestStuff> someData;                                
                        do
                        {
                            int start;
                            lock(myLock)
                            {
                               start = data.Count;
                            }

                            someKeys = GetDataFromService(start, limit);

                            lock (myLock)
                            {
                                if (someData != null && someData.Count > 0)
                                {
                                    data.AddRange(someData);
                                }
                            }

                        } while (hasData);
                    }
                    catch (AggregateException ex)
                    {
                       //Exception things
                    }

                }));
        }

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

Any inspiration to solve this without race conditions? I need to stick to .NET 4 if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure there's a way to do this without wasting some requests unless you know the actual limit. The code below might help eliminate the duplicate data as you will only query on each index once:

```
    private int _index = -1; // -1 so first request starts at 0
    private bool _shouldContinue = true;

    public IEnumerable<RequestStuff> GetAllData()
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task<RequestStuff>>();

        while (_shouldContinue)
        {
            tasks.Add(new Task<RequestStuff>(() => GetDataFromService(GetNextIndex())));
        }

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

        return tasks.Select(t => t.Result).ToList();
    }

    private RequestStuff GetDataFromService(int id)
    {
        // Get the data

        // If there's no data returned set _shouldContinue to false

        // return the RequestStuff;
    }

    private int GetNextIndex()
    {
        return Interlocked.Increment(ref _index);
    }
```

It could also be improved by adding cancellation tokens to cancel any indexes you know to be wasteful, i.e, if index 4 returns nothing you can cancel all queries on indexes above 4 that are still active.

Or if you could make a reasonable guess at the max index you might be able to implement an algorithm to pinpoint the exact limit before retrieving any data. This would probably only be more efficient if your guess was fairly accurate though.

Comment: My guesses would be at best willy nilly. Production wise it would be 100k records plus today but constantly growing. I also, if any request dies unfavorably after a number of retries have to throw away the data. My data request has to absolutely be complete

Comment: If the only way you can tell whether or not a request will return data is to make the request, I'm not sure if there's a very nice way to solve this. As I said in answer I'd try to keep track cancellation tokens and kill any unnecessary requests when a lower index invalidates them.

Comment: I like this answer and I see it working. Its sort of what I was thinking last evening after I was thinking about this. A little tweaking and it should do exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Are you attempting to force parallelism on the part of the remote service by issuing multiple concurrent requests?  Paging is generally used to limit the amount of data returned to only that which is needed, but if you need all of the data, then attempting to first page and then reconstruct it later seems like a poor design.  Your code becomes needlessly complex, difficult to maintain, you'll likely just move the bottleneck from code you control to somewhere else, and now you've introduced data integrity issues (what happens if all of these threads access different versions of the data you are trying to query?).  By increasing the complexity and number of calls, you are also increasing the likelihood of problems occurring (eg. one of the connections gets dropped).

Can you state the problem you are attempting to solve so perhaps instead we can help architect a better solution?

Comment: The service can support concurrent requests fairly well. The reason for paging is requesting more than say, 10,000 records causes the query to time out but multiple requests 5,000 records return within the server time out within my standards. The issue seems to be based on the limitations of the server making data queries for a specific request but it can do reasonable size chunks concurrently within what their server time out is. One large request bombs. Multiple smaller requests all complete just fine. I have no control over the service but they can support this and I wouldlike to leverage.